# why is CSS fontFamily defaulting to Times New Roman when the font is not found

Tags: css, fonts

I have a next app with a body that has a fontFamily: 'brandon-grotesque'. When a font from themeprovider (using material UI and `<Typography>`) doesn't exist or if it is a typo e.g. 'brandon-grotesk' from components inside of `<body>`-tag, i want the fontFamily to fallback to 'brandon-grotesque" and not Times New Roman. How do I do that?

also, it doesn't matter what I write in the fontFamily as long as it doesn't hit any imported fonts it defaults to Times New Roman

```
<body style={{ fontFamily: 'brandon-grotesque' }}>
     <Main />
     <NextScript />
</body>
```

i also thought about writing `font-family: 'my-font', inherit` but is not valid css

Answer (score -1):

Every browser will have some font fallback logic using fonts it expects to be in the host OS by default.

If you check the [CSS Fonts Module Level 3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-css-fonts-3-20180920/#font-family-prop), [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp) or [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Fundamentals), you'd find that the `font-family` property can take a comma-delimited list:

(Your use of curly braces is OK for use in react, but others should note it's not appropriate for raw CSS.)

```html
<body style="font-family: 'Brandon Grotesque', 'Brandon Grotesk'">
```

Also, you set the family name to `brandon-grotesque`, which looks like it might be a file name. You need to set it to the fonts family display name, not the file name.

Comment: inline styling in react is actually with curlybraces https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp, so its not wrong

Comment: Sorry, you didn't provide that context.

Comment: I mentioned "next app" which is a react framework, but no problem :)

Comment: @KimVu Apart from the syntax, was the answer I provided helpful in the react context?

Comment: Hmm not quite, I'm wondering why elements inside of body-tag won't get the font-family specified in the body-tag before getting the browser default. The font-family in body works when theres no font-family specified, but if theres something a misspelling, it default to browser and not body-tag